# How should I debug a "symbol X does not fit here" error when using c2hs?

Tags: haskell, c2hs

I'm new to using c2hs and having [this issue](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/Arbiter/pull/66#issuecomment-247859427).

I'm not sure how to start debugging this, and haven't found anything with a Google search or by looking through the issues on GitHub.

Where should I begin, and what are some resources that could help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dave Lee pointed out](https://github.com/ArbiterLib/Arbiter/pull/66#issuecomment-247861164), it's possible to pass use the `--c2hs-options` flag like so:

```
cabal ... --c2hs-options="-d trace"
```

I couldn't figure out how to make this work by adding to the `.cabal` or `stack.yaml` files, or by passing it on the command like in conjunction with `stack build` so just copied the command from the output of `stack build` and manually ran it with the additional flag:

```
/Users/py/projects/jspahrsummers/Arbiter/bindings/haskell/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.0.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build lib:arbiter --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file" --c2hs-options="-d trace"
```